# Send Email From My Application

Tags: android, email

I am Using Following Code for Send the Email from my application but problem is the Email application is open and my main application is closed so what is the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

My Code:-

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This is Email From Test Application");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: your application is not closed it got hide and you can access your app by pressing long home button and selecting the your app

Comment: My Problem is the Action chooser Popup is display but my main(base) application's activity is finished.

Comment: Hello Maneesh, but how to do my activity is displayed and emailchooser intent is display on the main activity's screen.

Comment: Can you post your whole code. From where you called emailIntent.?

Comment: I called Email Intent in Click event of Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jus checked ur code by writing it in onClick listener.Actually the email client is opening up and ur activity goes to onPause().When u click back its coming back to the activity from where it is launched.I dont see the application actually closing unless if u had given finish() in onPause() or onStop() in ur activity.

Comment: Thank u for Your Reply, and How to Activity Restart if i am click on back button.

Comment: You dont have to restart the activity when u press back button.when u press back the activity will go to onRestart() followed by onResume().so wats happening wen u press back button in ur app?